# jQuery Calculate the value for an input onchange of another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a calculator using jQuery/ javascript and html.
I have a list of items in a table. so when I click add item on a particular item, It appends a row in another table (Table B). each row in B has a different ID. Outside B is a disabled input field say Total = A1 + A2 + An. 
Within each row 2 things are calculated. Say A & P. The user enters 3 values, V1 V2 V3. And calculates A1 = (V1 * V2 * V3) and P1 = ((A1/Total)* 100). Note: this is inside the appended row. 
Everytime a value in Table B changes or a new Item is added, A & Total are recalculated. P is also recalculated with respect to value Total. My Issue is that I'm unable to recalculate P and display it in its proper row. It only updates the current edited row.

[image: Image Explanation Here]

```js
jQuery("#newRow").append('<tr id="TOYCal' + divID + '"><td><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px; display: inline;"  src="' + icon + '"/></td><td>' + title + '</td><td><input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control akCal" id="inputEmail" onChange="clearfield()" placeholder="Num" data-id="TOYCal' + divID + '"></td><td><input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control akCal V1" onChange="clearfield()" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Hrs/Day" max="24" min="1" data-id="TOYCal' + divID + '"></td><td><input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control akCal V2" onChange="clearfield()" min="1" id="unit" value="' + unit + '" placeholder="unit" data-id="TOYCal' + divID + '"></td><td><input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control akCal V3" onChange="clearfield()" id="inputEmail" min="1" placeholder="V3" data-id="TOYCal' + divID + '"></td><td><input disabled="" class="form-control ItemDay" id="focusedInput" data-id="TOYCal' + divID + '" type="number" value="" placeholder="W/Day"></td><td><input disabled="" class="form-control Percentage" id="focusedInput" data-id="TOYCal' + divID + '" type="number" value="" placeholder="Percent"></td></tr>');
```

```js
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.akCal', function() {
  //Get calculation values
  divID = jQuery(this).attr("data-ID");
  var V1 = jQuery('#' + divID + ' .akCal').val(); //alert("Number Items" + NumberItems);
  var V2 = jQuery('#' + divID + ' .ItemUnit').val(); //alert("Unit per item" +UnitPerItem);
  var V3 = jQuery('#' + divID + ' .ItemHours').val();

  var A = V1 * V2 * V3
  var initial = 0;
  var size = jQuery('.ItemDay').length;
  //alert("size " + size);

  jQuery('.ItemDay').each(function() { //ItemDay is id for row field
    var itemval = jQuery(this).val();
    // alert(itemval);
    var value = +initialWatt + +itemval;
    initial = value.toFixed(2);
  });

  jQuery('.totalkWh').val(initial);

  var percent = ((A / initial) * 100).toFixed(2);
  jQuery('#' + divID + ' .Percentage').val(percent);
});
```

Any Suggestions would be great.

Comment: pls fix your snippet

Comment: You need to add HTML to your snippet.

Comment: Far better to clone some real HTML, then modify it, than create *all of that* html in the append statement. This is quite an error prone and hard to read method.